# Authenticate Windows User in Electron App?

Tags: electron, windows-authentication, electron-builder

I’m working on an app that will be deployed to a fleet of corporate Windows laptops that are bound to Active Directory. Part of the app would need to allow the user to access the company's intranet URL. Would it be at all to automatically authenticate that user for their intranet without forcing another login? They've already logged into their AD account when logging into the laptop so I want to avoid it if possible. I've searched and haven't been able to find any information that covers this case.

Comment: Auth0 has some good support for Active Directory. https://auth0.com/authenticate/electron/active-directory

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your security strictness, the [username](https://www.npmjs.com/package/username) package could be a good fit for you.